# Methods and Objects in Python using dir() method

Tags: python, class, object

`dir()` methods gives us a list of attributes and methods that an object has. I want to separate the attributes and methods for an object. How can I achieve this.

```
i=10
print(dir(i)) 
# gives me the list of attributes and methods available for int object 'i'.
```

I want the attributes and methods for `int` object 'i' separately, how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I want the attributes and methods for int object 'i' separately, how I can do this?

Methods are just attributes on the type, so the methods (and class attributes I guess) are

```py
dir(type(i))
```

and the attributes are

```py
set(dir(i)) - set(dir(type(i)))
```

That will return an empty set, because ints don't have any attributes.

Also for the cases where that comes up, *properties* are attributes of the type as well.

Comment: Isn't `i.__doc__` an attribute?

Comment: @sj95126 it's an attribute of the class, not of the instance. Which I figured was a different situation, but I may have read too much into it.

Comment: Technically right, but I read the question as "which of the return values from `dir(i)` is an attribute vs a method" so the distinction didn't seem meaningful to the question.

Comment: That's probably fair, the question is really not very precise.

Answer (score 0):

Methods are attributes too, so I think the distinction you're looking for is whether an attribute is "callable", meaning you can put `()` after the attribute name to call it.

Generally speaking, to separate the callables (methods) from non-callables (plain attributes and properties), you can do this:

```
methods = [a for a in dir(i) if callable(getattr(i, a))]
attributes = [a for a in dir(i) if not callable(getattr(i, a))]
```

Which produces:

```
>>> methods
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', .....]
>>> attributes
['__doc__', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real']
```

(If you're using an older version of Python, `callable()` was removed in v3.0 but reappeared in v3.2)

Comment: A possible problem with this is that you can have non-method callable attributes, and this will treat them as methods. It would also classify e.g. associated types (a class set on an attribute for one reason or another e.g. a factory-type attribute) as methods, because in Python classes are of course callable.

Comment: Definitely agree that there's numerous edge cases, which is why I qualified it with "generally" - from an introductory perspective, the basic question is "what can I call and what can I query?"